# ReactJs, I have a weird issue with jsx and component elements

Tags: reactjs

Sorry that I just use pictures, I was thinking maybe pictures can tell a better story of what is happening...
The issue is that when I try to type an element like in test 1. It fails and if it was alone it would say the imported item is not being used...
What is wrong here?
It should render the same thing twice, for test 1 and 2.

[This is my app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5uZA.png)

[This is my component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dotXf.png)

[This is the output to the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ogadb.png)

Comment: Use upper case letter for your components, i.e. `AddTo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because name of component must be Capitalized. You can read more in here: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized

> When an element type starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a built-in component like  or  and results in a string 'div' or 'span' passed to React.createElement. Types that start with a capital letter like  compile to React.createElement(Foo) and correspond to a component defined or imported in your JavaScript file.